# Why do I get clear FM signals on my AM crystal radio?

Tags: circuit-design, crystal, frequency-modulation

I made a rudimentary radio:  long antenna out the window, coil and capacitor (both home-made) in parallel, diode to guitar amp in parallel to LC circuit.  It works!  Even my calculated L and C correspond to a few AM stations I can get.  BUT almost at all L and C combinations, two local FM stations are annoyingly strong!  I can imagine they put out enough power, and close enough, to flood my system, but why can I hear them well rather than static?? Nothing in my system should demodulate FM.  They are there with or without antenna, with or without ground, etc.!

Comment: Etither of : slope detection can provide FM to AM conversion OR : the FM channel is rebroadcast on a nearby AM transmitter.

Answer (score 3):

Slope detection: If your AM tuner is tuned to one side of the FM carrier frequency, the received signal strength will vary with the amplitude of the instantaneous frequency delta. Thus it will look a lot like an AM signal.

Comment: Thanks!  Update:  I kept stripping my system down to see when the FM drops out, and it never does.  I literally have a guitar amp with a diode and nothing else in a closed loop at the input, and I can hear very clearly Rock 101!  I can't see how this would be slope detection... How can I find if they rebroadcast a strong AM signal?  I emailed them, but no response...

Comment: Are you underneath there tower?! Your receiver (speakers included) are going act like a low-pass filter. It doesn't have to 'demodulate' FM, at least, not in the usual way. It just has to pick up their signal and your components do the rest. You'd need to filter out the VHF before it gets into the audio, to prevent hearing it.

Comment: I am 8 miles from transmitter...  I question how a filter would work, as I get their signal without (I.e. downstream of) an antenna.  Should I wrap my radio in grounded tin foil?  Anyone know how to make a low-pass filter to keep AM and reject FM?